# Unable to assign property Speed. NumberRange expected, got number

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I was making a script that creates a particle inside the player but i got the error "Unable to assign property Speed. NumberRange expected, got number "
Here is the code:

```
local LeftArmParticle = Instance.new('ParticleEmitter', player.Character["Left Arm"])
    
    LeftArmParticle.Texture = "rbxassetid://"..armAu
    LeftArmParticle.Speed = 1
    LeftArmParticle.Lifetime = 1
    LeftArmParticle.Rate = 50
```

Comment: It tells you pretty clearly what the issue is. Don't assign a number, assign a NumberRange https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/NumberRange

Comment: it worked for everything except rate, it set the rate to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty self-explanatory.  You need `LeftArmParticle.Speed = NumberRange.new(1)`, as the `NumberRange` type represents upper and lower bounds.  Since you want it to be a constant speed of 1, you do not need to specify both bounds.  You will have to do the same with the `Lifetime` property.